# Reading a CSV to vectors in objects

Tags: c++, class, oop, csv, vector

I'm trying to write code that will, on a line-by-line basis, pass numerical data from a CSV to an object's vector. The object's structure is as follows: the object itself (let's call it `CS`) is an enclosed space, within which resides a vector of objects (called `Points`) which each have a vector of objects (`Features`) with 3 variables. The first two variables in these Features are descriptors of the feature and the third is the actual value taken by a specific `Point[i].Feature[j]`. Each point has the same set of Features, and aside from third value being different, the descriptors are likewise identical. (edit: Sadly I can't change this structure as it's part of a larger framework which is out of my hands)

Currently, my CSV has one column per feature, the first two rows being the descriptors which apply for all points and the rest of the rows being each individual point's third feature value. It's been a while since my introductory C++ course and I'm finding it hard to think of a fast way to implement this, as my CSVs could become fairly large (my current upper limit is 50000 points having 2000 features, this will probably grow) and I wouldn't want to do something silly like rereading the first two lines every time for each point. I've looked around and most CSV solutions involve string CSVs, which I don't have to deal with, and simpler array objects in which the CSV is stored. The problem for me is simply going up a level each time I reach the end of the line and restarting the procedure for the next point, and I can't think of anything. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just create a temporary array of `Descriptor` objects which holds the two descriptors for each column and then read in your first row and create your `Point` objects from that. Afterwards you can just copy the descriptors from the `Point` a row above, e.g. `Point[i-csvWidth]`, and deallocate the `Descriptor` array.

Comment: Thanks, but that part is the least of my worries at the moment. I was thinking of doing that exact thing in a loop that precedes the one for the actual data but I'm not sure if I could easily resume in the file where I left off after closing that loop?

Comment: Then just don't close the stream. Construct it outside the preliminary loop and use the same instance for all your input.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I was nearly there, just used the wrong kind of variable to read in.

```
fstream myFile;
  myFile.open(filePath.c_str());
  if(!myFile){
    cout << "File \"" << filePath << "\" doesn't exist, exiting program." << endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  string line,line2,line3;
  Points.clear();

  //gets the range row
  getline(myFile,line);
  istringstream lineStream(line);
  //gets the nomin row
  getline(myFile,line2);
  istringstream lineStream2(line2);
  //gets the first person's traits
  getline(myFile,line3);
  istringstream lineStream3(line3);

  CultVec originalCultVec = CultVec(RNG);

  int val,val2,val3,val4;
  while (lineStream >> val && lineStream2 >> val2 && lineStream3 >> val3) {
        Feature feature;
        feature.Range = (char)val;
        feature.Nomin = (bool)val2;
        feature.Trait = (char)val3;
        originalCultVec.addFeature(feature);
    } // while
  Points.push_back(originalCultVec);

  while (getline(myFile,line)) {
    int i = 0;
    CultVec newVec = CultVec(RNG);
    istringstream lineStream4(line);
    while ( lineStream4 >> val4 ) {
      Feature newFeat = originalCultVec.getFeature(i);
      newFeat.Trait = (char)val4;
      newVec.addFeature(newFeat);
      i++;
        }
    Points.push_back(newVec);
  }
```